# How to implement web applications more efficiently?

Tags: database, jsf, web-applications, primefaces, jsf-1.2

I've been developing a website using JSF & PrimeFaces. At the time of development, I noticed that there're 2 bottlenecks for any web applications. Correct me if I'm wrong.

The bottlenecks are:

1. I've used Hibernate framework for persistence layer. Now if a change
   occurs in database, then there's no way to reflect that in scoped
   beans. Hibernate has dynamic-update attribute which helps to update
   only the affected records of the table [at the time of  persisting]. But I've not found similar
   kind of mechanism by which I can always get updated DAO. Here,
   developer has to take responsibility of updating them by using
   `session.refresh()` method, which just reloads the entire object
   tree from database table. So,for each small database changes, I
   think the caching functionality of DAO [in Hibernate] is missed
   since every time they're evicted from session cache. In a word, database updates doesn't trigger DAO updates.
2. After updating DAO, if I want to reflect the changes in view level, then I had to take help of Primeface sockets [PrimePush] since refreshing the pages every time isn't a good implementation & primeface socket allows updating of specific ids. So, that means for each DAO fields, I've to take help of many different Primeface sockets, each one having unique channel. Also sending messages to those different sockets has to be done by developer in bean codes.

So, the question is how these can be handled in a efficient way? Is there any other technologies/framework which handles these issues so that developer doesn't have to worry about?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you shoule be doing like :

Hibernate Persistence Layer (have DAO performing CRUD operations)

Managed Beans which access your DAO

View (Primefaces) using BackBean updating the View.

You don't need PrimePush or something. It should be refreshed by actions in your Views

Comment: Hibernate doesn't provide DAO auto-updating feature.So, for conveying the information like "Hey, I'm changed.Please update your corresponding page part where I'm rendered",I think primepush is required.An example would be where you update a post in social networking site & your friends can see the update instantaneously.